# Replace special characters in a string with their UTF-8 encoded character java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to convert only the special characters to their UTF-8 equivalent character.
For example given a String: `Abcds23#$_ss`, it should get converted to `Abcds23353695ss`.

The following is how i did the above conversion: 
 The utf-8 in hexadecimal for `#` is 23 and in decimal is 35. The utf-8 in hexadecimal for `$` is 24 and in decimal is 36. The utf-8 in hexadecimal for `_` is 5f and in decimal is 95.

I know we have the `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` method. But I want to replace specific character with their specific UTF-8 equivalent.

How do I do the same in java?

Comment: why did "#$" become "353695" ?

Comment: Following is how the conversion happened:
The utf-8 in hexadecimal for # is 23 and in decimal is 35
 The utf-8 in hexadecimal for $ is 24 and in decimal is 36
The utf-8 in hexadecimal for _ is 5f and in decimal is 65

Sry edited the question it is Abcds23#$_ss and not Abcds23#$ss

Comment: Never put more information into comments, update your question instead.

Comment: Doable but you will not be able to convert the string back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you define "special characters", but this function should give you an idea:

```
public static String convert(String str) 
{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(index);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))
            buf.append(ch);
        else
            buf.append(str.codePointAt(index));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

@Test
public void test()
{
    Assert.assertEquals("Abcds23353695ss", convert("Abcds23#$_ss"));
}
```

Comment: Yes any character other than an alphanumeric character is a special character in my case . How is your program converting the special character to UTF-8 equivalent , as i donot see UTF-8 mentioned anywhere?Or is UTF-8 the default encoding used in java?

Comment: @user2713255 I think the secret lies in `Character.codePointAt`, yes I assume UTF-8 is the default

Comment: @user2713255 `Character.codePointAt`returns the Unicode code point at the given index.

Comment: You can get the codepoint simply by casting the `char` to `int`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2006544/2568885

Comment: Checking that the character is alphanumeric can be made more readaable: `Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)`

Comment: @binoternary I adopted your `isLetterOrDigit` suggestion, but I think `codePointAt` is more readable than simply casting. ;-)

Comment: @binoternary Actually, casting char to int, gets you the same thing: one UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses java 8 or above and checks whether a Unicode code point (symbol) is a letter or digit, pure ASCII (< 128) and otherwise output the Unicode code point as string of the numerical value.

```
static String convert(String str) {
    int[] cps = str.codePoints()
            .flatMap((cp) ->
                Character.isLetterOrDigit(cp) && cp < 128
                ? IntStream.of(cp)
                : String.valueOf(cp).codePoints())
                    .toArray();
    return new String(cps, 0, cps.length);
}
```

`String.codePoints()` yields an IntStream, `flatMap` adds IntStreams in a single flattened stream, and `toArray` collects it in an array. So we can construct a new String from those code points. Entirely Unicode safe.

Conversion is not undoable without delimiters.

---

***On Unicode:***

**Unicode** numbers symbols, called **code points**, from 0 upwards, into the 3 byte range.

To be coded (formated) in bytes there exist **UTF-8** (multi-byte), **UTF-16LE** and **UTF-16BE** (2byte-sequences) and **UTF-32** (code points as-is more or less).
Java string constants in a .class file are in UTF-8. A String is composed of UTF-16BE `char`s. And String can give code points as above. So java by design uses Unicode for text.

Comment: Why is `cp< 128` condition required and what does it do? In my case any character other than alphabets and digits are considered as special characters

Comment: There are letters like `ü`, Greek ones, Arabic digits, and so on. Pure ASCII is upto 127, Using the class Character one could also formulate it elswise that the script/block is ASCII, but that is a bit more verbose.