# How to get hexadecimal representation of unicode character?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

How can I get hexadecimal representation of unicode character? For example when I look unicode table for the "ā" character it shows U+0101;

```
Code   Glyph Decimal Html
U+0101  ā    &#257;  &amacr;
```

But my code outputs;

```
[-60, -127]
```

I don't get How can I achieve U+0101 with this byte array. Here is my code

```
String s = "ā";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006533/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-characters-code