# Different string encoding of same string in Python and Java

Tags: java, python

I have a text file from which I am reading lines and processing each line one by one.

I came across this line:

```
(T)he film is never sure to make a clear point – even if it seeks to rely on an ambiguous presentation.
```

Between `point` and `even` I have three characters , `-` and .

I tried printing out the characters as integers.

In Java:

```
String input = "(T)he film is never sure to make a clear point – even if it seeks to rely on an ambiguous presentation.";
int[] ords = new int[input.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < ords.length; i++)
    ords[i] = (int) input.charAt(i);
```

which gives:

```
[40, 84, 41, 104, 101, 32, 102, 105, 108, 109, 32, 105, 115, 32, 110, 101, 118, 101, 114, 32, 115, 117, 114, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 109, 97, 107, 101, 32, 97, 32, 99, 108, 101, 97, 114, 32, 112, 111, 105, 110, 116, 32, 8211, 32, 101, 118, 101, 110, 32, 105, 102, 32, 105, 116, 32, 115, 101, 101, 107, 115, 32, 116, 111, 32, 114, 101, 108, 121, 32, 111, 110, 32, 97, 110, 32, 97, 109, 98, 105, 103, 117, 111, 117, 115, 32, 112, 114, 101, 115, 101, 110, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46]
```

In Python:

```
def get_ords(string):
    return map(lambda x: ord(x), string)
```

which gives:

```
[40, 84, 41, 104, 101, 32, 102, 105, 108, 109, 32, 105, 115, 32, 110, 101, 118, 101, 114, 32, 115, 117, 114, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 109, 97, 107, 101, 32, 97, 32, 99, 108, 101, 97, 114, 32, 112, 111, 105, 110, 116, 32, 226, 128, 147, 32, 101, 118, 101, 110, 32, 105, 102, 32, 105, 116, 32, 115, 101, 101, 107, 115, 32, 116, 111, 32, 114, 101, 108, 121, 32, 111, 110, 32, 97, 110, 32, 97, 109, 98, 105, 103, 117, 111, 117, 115, 32, 112, 114, 101, 115, 101, 110, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46]
```

In java's result, the three characters , `-` and  are represented by `8211` and in python it is represented as `226, 128, 147` i.e. `'\xe2', '\x80', '\x93'`. This discrepancy is resulting in different results when I process it in java and python.

I also noticed that if I remove , `-` and  from the string, the results are same for both.

Is it possible to solve this issue without having to remove the special characters.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2006580) could help you.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not using it as a unicode string in Python (`u` prefix in Python 2).

This can be illustrated by the following code (using the relevant part of your example):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

x = u"t – e"
y = "t – e"

def get_ords(s):
    return map(lambda x: ord(x), s)

print "x: %s" % (get_ords(x),)
print "y: %s" % (get_ords(y),)
```

The result is:

```
x: [116, 32, 8211, 32, 101]
y: [116, 32, 226, 128, 147, 32, 101]
```

This Python documentation about Unicode should be of interest: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

When reading from a file, you can use [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html), otherwise, you're not reading the file as Unicode:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('test.txt','r','utf-8') as f:
    x = f.read()

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    y = f.read()
```

(This produces the same results as above.)

Note that, in Java, the encoding used for reading may also depend on the value of the `file.encoding` system property. (It depends on how you read the file, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html )

Comment: very thorough, comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the string has the same encoding in both. For example, for python I'd do something like the following to get it into utf8:

```
def get_ords(string):
    string = string.encode('utf-8')
    return map(lambda x: ord(x), string)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by @Bruno is very good, I was able to solve my issue using the following function:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return unidecode(unicode(text, encoding="utf-8"))
```

For any string I used `remove_non_ascii` and the same in Java.