# Is it possible to implement the compare FI to compare two different type of objects?

Tags: object, interface, functional-programming, compare

I'm studying how to use the FIs and the lambda expressions and I was wondering if I could compare two objects but of a different type such as an Integer object and a String object. I've seen them, sometimes, being used interchangeably like a Char becoming and Integer or a CharSequence becoming a String. That made me think about comparing them since they all come from the Object superclass.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here.
However, I would guess you saw a char being compared to an Integer when it was used to represent its Unicode value (cfr.: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006533/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-characters-code)).
The relationship between String and CharSequence instead is that of a class implementing an interface (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323962/exact-difference-between-charsequence-and-string-in-java) for more information)