# String array with letters to int convertion

Tags: java, arrays

I got this array of string

```
String s1[] = {"H","E","L","L","O"};
```

and a method to convert it into int

```
    public static int[] String2Int(String[] k){
    int[] arrayBuffer = new int[k.length];

    for (int i=0; i < k.length; i++)
    {
        //arrayBuffer[i] = Integer.parseInt(k[i]);
        arrayBuffer[i] = Integer.parseInt(k[i]);
    }
    return arrayBuffer;
```

I want the decimal values of the characters but no luck on getting it. 
Google is only helping with if the string were a number.

Comment: What do you mean decimal values of the characters? you mean ascii value of character or parsing like "43" = 43? or 'A' = 65 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006533/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-characters-code#2006580

Comment: yes, A = 65. Sorry for not writting that also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Unicode character's code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006533/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-characters-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't convert it to integer. It should be

```
 arrayBuffer[i] =k[i].charAt(0);
```

That way you get the ASCII value of char and gets assigned to int.

Edit :

You can also use `arrayBuffer[i] = Character.codePointAt(input, 0);` as pointed in comments.

Comment: why not `Character.codePointAt(input, 0);`

Comment: @Tschallacka well both works. Isn't it?

Comment: It handles also the edge cases where it isn't always straightforward what code point it is, it handles surrogate pairs so you'll get a consistent output back.

Comment: arrayBuffer[i] =k[i].charAt(0); 
Did the trick for ruinning the program. thanks!

Comment: @Tschallacka Fair enough. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(String2Int("HELLO")));
    }
    public static int[] String2Int(String k)
    {
        int[] arrayBuffer = new int[k.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBuffer.length; i++)
        {
            //arrayBuffer[i] = Integer.parseInt(k[i]);
            arrayBuffer[i] = k.charAt(i);
        }
        return arrayBuffer;
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
[72, 69, 76, 76, 79]
```

#### Explanation

`char` and `int` is almost the same in Java. You don't need to parse it, you just implicitly cast it by asigning it to the `int[]`. Also you shouldn't take a `String[]` as an argument, that makes no sense. A String is already almost a `char[]`. So either take a `String`, or a `char[]`. In my example I've used a `String` because that is more convenient to call.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Java 8 Stream API:

```
public static int[] convert(String[] strings)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(strings);
    return Arrays.stream(strings)
            .mapToInt(str -> Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(0)))
            .toArray();
}
```

I assume you dont need to check that the input strings contain exactly one character.